# XSLT Match issue

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XSLT question:

Suppose I have this XML

```
 <items>
    <item>
      <type>dog</type>
      <color>brown</color>
    </item>
    <item>
      <type>dog</type>
      <color>brown</color>
    </item>
    <item>
      <type/>
      <color>none</color>
    </item>
    <item>
      <type>dog</type>
      <color>black</color>
    </item>
 </items>
```

If I use the following in xsl 1.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="item[type='dog']">
        <item>
            <itemType><xsl:value-of select="type"/></itemType>
            <itemColor><xsl:value-of select="color"/></itemColor>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It will only show the first matches before the empty node.

Is there anything I am overlooking?

Comment: This cannot be answered without more context. According to your sample, the template matches any item of type "dog", regardless of its position. There must be something else you do not mention.

Comment: Aja! Did you ask this because [Built-in Template Rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule)? The `item` with empty `type` child will also be matched by the built-in "any element" rule

Comment: "Is there anything I am overlooking?" - Yes. Unfortunately we don't know what. The problem is in the code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: Sorry, but I edited the post with the exact situation. The answer by Andy B. Worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example works for me when I load the `test.xml` in IE8. I get the output `dog dog dog`

Save this as `text.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<items>
    <item>
      <type>dog</type>
    </item>
    <item>
      <type>dog</type>
    </item>
    <item>
      <type>cat</type>
    </item>
    <item>
      <type>dog</type>
    </item>
</items>
```

Save this as test.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="item"/> <!-- default item match (prints nothing) -->
<xsl:template match="item[type='dog']">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If this is not helping, please edit your question with more information about your problem.